# meta viewport: can not use "width=640" with "initial-scale=1.0"?

Tags: html, css, viewport

when I set viewport with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640">
```

I can create a square div takes half of the screen by following css

```
.sq {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

[image]

but I after I modify it to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, initial-scale=1.0">
```

it seems broken, the square with 320px width takes more than half of the screen.

[image]

what does "initial-scale=1.0" do here, can anyone tell me the details ?

Answer (score 0):

put px as units

```
<meta name="viewport" content:"width=640px">
```